# warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] str = cleanStr(line);

Tags: c

I tried to compile my code written in C. but it generates this error :

```
generate.c:128:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 str = cleanStr(line);
     ^
```

here is a part of my file generate.c

```
118-const int processParsing(char *line, int *current_lvl, FILE* outFile)
119-{
120
121  int ret = RET_OK;
122 const char * str = NULL;
123 int level = 0;
124 char buff [50 + 1] = {0};
125 char buff1[50 + 1] = {0};
126 char buff2[50 + 1] = {0};
127
128 str = cleanStr(line);
129 if (ret == RET_OK) {
     /* le reste du code */
     }

and here is my function **cleanstr**



const char * cleanStr(char *line)
{
int ret = RET_OK ;
while (*line== ' ') {
    line++;
}
if (line[strlen(line)-1] == '\n') {
    line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
}
return line;
}
```

I really can't understand what is the problem .Is it with 'const' in cleanstr function declaration ? how can I please correct this error ?

Comment: Is your cleanStr function defined before the processParsing function ? Or do you at least have a prototype for cleanStr that comes befdore processParsing ?

Comment: my cleanStr function is declared in another file.c but i put the prototype in a file.h and I included it in the mainFile.c

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate. Something the accepted answer to that question doesn't mention is that the "implicit `int`" rule was dropped in C99. Calling a function with no visible declaration is now illegal; a compiler won't just assume it returns `int`. Many compiler still implement the old behavior, which is why you got that warning.

Comment: @souha then you have made some mistake when you did just that.

Comment: The error is in `generate.c`, not `mailFile.c`. Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: I have three functions : parse.c , generate.c and main.c ( the main file). both of parse.c and generate.c use the cleanStr function. I didn't know where to put the ' cleanStr function so iit can be visible for both parse.c and generate.c

Comment: @souha: Put the *definition* of `cleanStr` in any `.c` file. Put a one-line *declaration*, `const char * cleanStr(char *line);`, in some `.h` file that's `#include`d by each `.c` file that needs it.